# InnerHtml in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I have `<td id="StatusPreview" runat="server"></td>` and it gets populated by a js function by:

```
document.getElementById('StatusPreview').innerHTML = Ext.getCmp('TYComboEdit').getRawValue();
```

Now, I would like to change the content of the td in `c#` when a button is clicked.

I created the following method:

```
    protected void hiddentoggletofrenchBackend(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        this.StatusPreview.InnerHtml = "aaaaa";
    }
```

It does not change the content on the td. **However**, if I place an alert after setting the `InnerHtml` it alerts `aaaaa` even though the td content has not changed to reflect this. If I place an alert before setting the `InnerHtml` the alert is blank.

How can I change the InnerHtml of the div?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

If I change the html to `<td id="StatusPreview" runat="server">q</td>` the alert shows `q` if it is placed before setting `InnerHtml`, and switches to `aaaaa` if placed after. 
It is as if `InnerHtml` is taking the value on pageload, not the current value.

Comment: I believe that would be `InnerText` for C# not `InnerHtml`.

Comment: is this all done in an asp.net form?  A windows form hosting a browser control?

Comment: @Mike_G it is done in an Ext.NET form (which is based off of asp.net)

Comment: @Greg I tried that, but sadly, nothing.

Comment: do you re-render the div after you change it's content?  if not then you would not see any change in the inner html because the displayed page was not updated, even though the underlying html has changed

Comment: td is a table cell not a div.

Comment: @StephenKennedy too many things running through my mind, typo :p FIXED

Comment: @theDarse I did not. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: there are any number of js libraries that can do that, if using the mvvm pattern, knockout or angular come to mind, you could simply use jquery to do it.  I would honestly use javascript for this unless you have a specific requirement you need to use c# for

Comment: @theDarse the requirement is that `aaaaa` will ultimately be the value  returned from a preexisting c# function

Comment: Go and get yourself a free tool called Fiddler and then you can see  exactly what your browser is requesting and what the server is returning. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update an ASP.NET control during a DirectEvent, you should call the .Update() method.

```
protected void hiddentoggletofrenchBackend(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
    this.StatusPreview.InnerHtml = "aaaaa";
    this.StatusPreview.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `runat=server` to a `td` element turns it into a [HtmlTableCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecell(v=vs.110).aspx) control. The relevant property to set the inner text on this control is [InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innertext(v=vs.110).aspx).

As this is a server side control, any change is only going to happen after postback to the server. That would mean the entire page is reloaded and re-rendered. You can examine requests to the server and the server responses with the free tool [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Assuming a postback is actually happening, are you sure you're not overwriting the new inner text with JavaScript which runs on page load?

Do you even need to do a postback for this? If "aaaaa" is not a placeholder for what will become a database or some other lookup, I would render the alternate text into a hidden div or into some JavaScript and do the text change entirely in JavaScript.

Comment: I think I am going to do as you suggested and `render the alternate text into a hidden div or into into some JavaScript and do the text change entirely in JavaScript.` Thank you!

Comment: Ah, seems I wrote "into into". Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I created a div `<div id="statuspreviewLangName" runat="server"></div>`, ran this c# `this.statuspreviewLangName.InnerHtml = "asd";` then this js `document.getElementById('StatusPreview').innerHTML = document.getElementById('statuspreviewLangName').innerHTML;` Because the js does not see the changed div.... Back to square 1 :(