# html is not showing as html in div

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to set HTML inside a div in my code, but the end result looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
protected void grdTags_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string RelatedText = grdTags.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
    dv.InnerHtml = RelatedText;
}
```

Here is the ASPX:

```
<div id="dv" runat="server">

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554041/innerhtml-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're passing in text into HTML. Consider using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()

I've not tested this, but try:

```
dv.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(grdTags.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text);
```

Comment: I am getting this now : &lt;br&gt;&lt;h3&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;AFF_&quot;&gt;Affirmed&lt;/

Comment: I tried HtmlDecode and that works.. I will update your answer